# Reconciling declaration and usage syntax of arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, syntax, declaration

In C, 'array syntax' is just *syntactic sugar* for pointer syntax. That is 
`a[4]` translates to `*(a+4)`.

But this is not always true.

Surely the following is absurd,

```
int a[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int *(a+4) = {1,2,3,4};
```

This won't compile.

Anyways, I was wondering if anyone has any insights regarding this discrepancy. To me it seems strange to have two different classes of syntax. One for declaration, and one for actual usage.

Is that what's going on?

Comment: your second line should be more like: `int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4); a[1] = 1; a[2] = 2;`...etc...

Comment: Apart from SnakeDoc's correct comment, you have other instances where more than one syntax is correct. V.g., `(*myPointerToStruct).myMember` is the same than `myPointerToStruct->myMember`. Or, with arrays `a[0]` is the same than `*a` (the first form is better)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general inspiration behind C's (admittedly confusing) declaration syntax is that "declaration follows use". So, for example:

```
int *ptr;
```

happens to declare `ptr` as an object of type `int*` (which is why some people prefer to write `int* ptr;`), but if you follow the syntax what it *really* means is that `*ptr` is of type `int`.

But don't take the idea that "declaration follows use" too literally. It's not an actual language rule, and it doesn't apply in all cases. It's a good start in understanding C's declaration syntax, but it is by no means the whole story.

For a simple array definition:

```
int arr[10];
```

you could say that `arr[10]` is of type `int`. And the expression `arr[10]` *is* of type `int`, but of course it refers to an array element that doesn't exist.

Arrays and pointers are not equivalent. The array indexing operator is "syntactic sugar" for an operation involving pointer arithmetic: `x[y]` means `*(x+y)`. But that applies only to the array indexing operator `[]`. It does not apply to array declaration syntax.

Many (but not all) forms of declaration can be understood by treating the declaration as an expression, with the type name telling you what type that expression has. But not all expressions can be transformed into declarations. There is no declaration corresponding to the expression `x+y` -- or to the expression `*(x+y)`.

The most important thing to remember about arrays and pointers is that they are *different things*. The indexing operator `[]` is defined to operate on a pointer value (that pointer must point to an element of an array object). An expression of array type is, in most but not all contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element; the exceptions are when it's the operand of unary `&`, of unary `sizeof`, or when it's a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array.

The meaning of C declarations is determined by the language grammar. "Declaration follows use" is not part of that grammar.

Comment: But why are there these two grammers inside the same language? Why not just one grammer!

Comment: @captaincurrie: There *is* a single grammar; you can see it in the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). There are separate parts for declarations and expressions because a single syntax for both wouldn't work. Are you saying C should strictly follow the "declaration follows use" principle in all cases? Feel free to demonstrate how that could be made to work. Seriously, that would be interesting to see. But it would have to be in a new language; fundamentally changing C's grammar at this point would break existing code, which is a non-starter.

Comment: @captaincurrie: C is not 100% consistent because it *evolved*; it has a number of features that didn't exist in early C, or in its ancestor language B, and they had to be added without breaking existing code. Some Lisp dialects are probably close to being 100% syntactically consistent -- but C is definitely not Lisp.

Comment: Thank you. I think i need a good study of program language implementation/design to feel satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

The "syntactic sugar" you mention applies to the *postfix-expression* `[...]`. What you have in your examples are *declaration*'s. Both use the same characters, but the two constructs belong to completely different branches of the syntax tree.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just get this feeling like 'why would you have two different syntaxs inside the same language'. Feels like some impurity that shouldn't be there. I want consistency!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [C-faq](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html):

> Saying that arrays and pointers are ''equivalent'' means neither that
>   they are identical nor even interchangeable. What it means is that
>   array and pointer arithmetic is defined such that a pointer can be
>   conveniently used to access an array or to simulate an array. In other
>   words, as Wayne Throop has put it, it's ''pointer arithmetic and array
>   indexing [that] are equivalent in C, pointers and arrays are
>   different.'')

In addition to that, quoting from [this](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/practdiff.html) question in C-faq:

> An array is a single, preallocated chunk of contiguous elements (all
>   of the same type), fixed in size and location. A pointer is a
>   reference to any data element (of a particular type) anywhere. A
>   pointer must be assigned to point to space allocated elsewhere, but it
>   can be reassigned (and the space, if derived from malloc, can be
>   resized) at any time. A pointer can point to an array, and can
>   simulate (along with malloc) a dynamically allocated array, but a
>   pointer is a much more general data structure.

So arrays are more than *syntactic sugar* for pointers.

Comment: I'd go further than the FAQ does. Saying that arrays and pointers are "equivalent" is simply wrong. They aren't.

Comment: An array is a concept, a mathematical object we can operate on. A pointer is an actual thing.

Comment: @captaincurrie: Well, matrix is the mathematical object you refer to. Arrays and pointers are both "actual things" :P But it's not a different notation for the same thing. They're fundamentally different.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer syntax works because that's how C works behind the scene and doesn't prevent you from abusing it.

`int a[4]` tell the compiler that you want to create a variable of a given size in the stack (4 x sizeof(int)), so if you want to do it using a pointer syntax, you have to find an other way to tell it to do that, either using `malloc`, or by allocating `double b[2]` (or anything else of the same size) and casting it around.

Comment: How do you know `double b[2]` is the same size as `int a[4]`? It isn't necessarily. And defining an array of `double` and treating it as an array of `int` is unsafe; for one thing the alignments might not match.